# Does the process inside of the docker image still need to be managed?

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Say I am running a java web application inside of my docker container that runs on elastic beanstalk (or any other framework for that matter).

I still am responsible for making sure my process has some kind of process managaement to make sure it is running correct?  i.e. supervisord or runit

Or is this something that EB will somehow manage?

Answer (score 1):

When the process inside the container stops, so too does the container (designed to run that single process). So you don't have to manage the process inside your container, instead rely on the system managing your containers to restart them. For example "services" in Docker Swarm and Replication Controllers in Kubernetes  are designed to keep a desired number of containers running. When one dies a new one takes its place

Comment: so in the context of elastic beanstalk I wonder what happens, or does that mean I have to configure this in docker?  Is there a link you can point me to b/c I kind of havent' grasped docker that well yet!